Trying to iterate jinja lists in cloud-init template
Is it possible to iterate multiple jinja lists? Trying to build an array with values, then iterate those values into the rendered output.
Here is what I have tried, the for loop only seems to iterate the users list.  I am trying to populate user data from the jinja lists defined (user, hash, key), then render the values for each user.
## template: jinja
#cloud-config
{% set users = ['usr1','usr2'] %}
{% set hashes = ['$6$usr1-hash/','$6$usr2-hash'] %}
{% set keys = ['ssh-ed25519 usr1-key','ssh-ed25519 usr2-key'] %}
{% for user in users %}

users:
  - name: {{ user }}
{% set group = 'wheel' %}
    groups: {{ group }}
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: {{ hashes }}
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - {{ keys }}
    shell: /bin/bash
user = {{ user }}
hash = {{ hash }}
key = {{ key }}

{% endfor %}

This just populate the entire list,  what is the correct syntax to have it iterate all three lists.  I tried the index values (ex: hashes.1) and this give me the same value for each user.
Example of output:
users:
  - name: usr1
    groups: wheel
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: ['$6$usr1-hash/', '$6$usr2-hash']
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ['ssh-ed25519 usr1-key', 'ssh-ed25519 usr2-key']
    shell: /bin/bash
user = usr1
hash = CI_MISSING_JINJA_VAR/hash
key = CI_MISSING_JINJA_VAR/key



users:
  - name: usr2
    groups: wheel
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: ['$6$usr1-hash/', '$6$usr2-hash']
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ['ssh-ed25519 usr1-key', 'ssh-ed25519 usr2-key']
    shell: /bin/bash
user = usr2
hash = CI_MISSING_JINJA_VAR/hash
key = CI_MISSING_JINJA_VAR/key


Desired output:
users:
  - name: usr1
    groups: wheel
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: '$6$usr1-hash/'
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - 'ssh-ed25519 usr1-key'
    shell: /bin/bash
user = usr1
hash = '$6$usr1-hash/'
key = 'ssh-ed25519 usr1-key'



users:
  - name: usr2
    groups: wheel
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: '$6$usr2-hash'
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - 'ssh-ed25519 usr2-key'
    shell: /bin/bash
user = usr2
hash = '$6$usr2-hash'
key = 'ssh-ed25519 usr2-key'



Of course it only iterates the users, because that's the only for loop in the template. What's the expected result? for the other lists a loop might not be the optimal solution, a simple join might be better.

Expected result, is to render the list of users usr1, usr2 as well as the hashes list and the keys list.
Should give one user block (- name) with the values from the respective lists.  I will do some searching on join.  Makes sense it only iterates the users,  just don't know what step I need to iterate the other lists as well.

What ended up working for my needs.
## template: jinja
#cloud-config

{% set users = ['joe' , 'ansible' , 'foo' , 'bar'] %}
{% set hashes = '$6$eMxyzabc123/Mzt/','$6$ansiblehash','$7$foo-hash','$2$barhash' %}
{% set keys = ['- ssh-ed25519 joekey XX-ed25519-ansible','- ssh-ed25519 ansible_keyAAAAC3Nz','fookey','barkey' %}
{% set group = 'wheel' %}

users:
{% for i in users %}
{% set user = users[loop.index-1] %}
{% set hash = hashes[loop.index-1] %}
{% set key = keys[loop.index-1] %}
  - name: {{ user }}
    groups: {{ group }}
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: {{ hash }}
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      {{ key }}
    shell: /bin/bash
{% endfor %}


